# Resque error when running on my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque

When I am running the project locally and have not got resque running I will get an error message when using enqueue. I understand that totally as the resque server is not running.

Is there a way to catch that error instead so that I can display it as a flash error message instead of halting execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is do the jobs with resque when `Rails.env == production` or `staging`. In development, the jobs are done directly.

Comment: so if in production do `Resque.enqueue(MyJob)` but in Development do `MyJob.perform` directly? I would rather just have that exception show in a red flash message though.

Comment: Yup something like that. I don't know what kind of error is raised when resque is not running, so I don't know if you can and how to catch it